# plot of a matrix of type character

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to plot a matrix of type character:

```
m=matrix(data=c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C","B"),nrow=4,ncol=2)
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "B"  "C" 
[4,] "B"  "B"
```

with a defined set of colours

```
A="Yellow"
B="Blue"
C="Green"
```

Should I pass from matrix to ascii and use **image()** from **sp package**?

I am looking fro something like this:

[image]

Comment: `image` is from pkg:graphics. The second answer below should satisfy, at least when you swap rows and columns. You can look for the desired green with this code: `grep("green", colors(), value=TRUE)`. "darkgreen" was too dark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It rather depends on what you meant by "plot a matrix":

```
 m2 <- m
 m2[] <- c("yellow", "blue","green")[match(m, c("A","B","C"))]
 m2
#------------
 [,1]     [,2]   
[1,] "yellow" "blue" 
[2,] "yellow" "green"
[3,] "blue"   "green"
[4,] "blue"   "blue" 
#------------
plot(row(m2), col(m2), col=m2, pch=18, cex=4)
```

This plots solid diamonds of the specified color at the matrix locations determined by the row and columns of matrix m. Another way with `image`:

```
m2[] <- match(m, c("A","B","C"))
mode(m2) <- "numeric"
m2
image(1:nrow(m2), 1:ncol(m2), m2, col=c("yellow", "blue","green"))
```

[image]

Comment: `grid.raster(m2, interpolate=FALSE)` if you don't want any axes etc.

Comment: That threw an error with the m2 object above and when divided by max(m2) I get grey-scale.

Comment: I meant the first m2 (color names)

Comment: aha. I see. It does overlay an existing plot.

Comment: Hi! I've found recently this function that can also help on plotting matrix datasets : http://www.phaget4.org/R/image_matrix.html

Comment: The problem you posed was plotting matrices of "character" with a particular color mapping. The referenced function is described as working with "numeric" values.